# Bootstrap não funciona no Angular V-6

Tags: bootstrap-3, angular, angular-5

Não estou conseguindo usar o Bootstrap na minha pagina:

- instalei a versão 3 `npm install --save bootstrap@3` no
  `angular.json`
- coloquei o caminho: `"styles": ["../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" "src/styles.css"],`

Comment: Tenta reiniciar o ng serve

Comment: veja se o caminho ../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css existe dentro do node_modules do seu projeto